# Modifying the latest EK-04 LED controller to have the LEDs stay steady on by default at power up

Tags: led, controller

In June 2023 I bought several of these latest LEDs string lights powered by 120VAC featuring a tiny EK-04 white controller.
On the board there are two ICs, one is a MB10F bridge rectifier.
The other is a small 6 pin controller IC with two outputs connected to the LED wires. On the controller IC is written the letters 806B.
The only other parts are a 150K resistor, a 5K resistor, a small ceramic cap, and a push button switch. I am reluctant to experiment on this without knowing more about the controller IC and the LED driver circuit.

Like everyone who has ever bought one of these LED strings, I just want the LEDs to stay on permanently from power up.
I can't even guess why the designers did not figure out no one wants this flashing by default. They would sell far more.

I just wondered if there is a mod to forever stop the flashing for this latest design controller?
There seem to be many variants which can be modified to do this. Hopefully this one can also because I have several. Thanks.

Comment: You could replace the controller IC with one that works the way you want, but if this is directly connected to mains voltage through a rectifier, it's not the safest thing to mess with. If you want to hack a controller, pick one that runs off a low voltage, isolated supply.

Comment: Yeah, embarrassingly easy.
I thought they might have done something more sophisticated than series high voltage.
I didn't expect the controller IC to work at +/-55V dc either!
I didn't see any electrolytics to smooth the rectified AC either...
The mod is:
Remove the 6-pin controller IC and connect the other floating output of the bridge rectifier to the two floating LED strings.
No more annoying flashing!
To the designers of these LED boxes please make them without the controller IC so they are always on.
Until then we will be removing the controller ICs and throwing them in the trash.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter capacitor of low value like 2.2uF/450V or 3.3uF/450V after the bridge rectifier. the leds would stop flashing.

The controller uses the ac supply frequency as a clock pulse.

Using a capacitor would also stop the annoying flickering.

Never bypass the controller and connect leds directly to the bridge rectifier. that may damage the leds.

Comment: I fail to see any mention of an flicker issue.